Ampleness of the pullback of the relative dualizing sheaf of $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n+1}}\rightarrow\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$
There is a natural map $f : \overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n+1}}\rightarrow\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$ identifying the source with the universal family over the target. Let $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ be the canonical sections of $f$. Let $\omega_f$ denote the relative dualizing sheaf. Are the pullbacks $\sigma_i^*\omega_f$ ample? are they anti-ample? (i.e., is its inverse ample?)
Since these are generally stacks, by (anti-)ampleness I mean (anti-)ample after pulling back to a finite flat scheme cover. (I think this is the right definition)
For $(g,n) = (1,1)$, this is the Hodge bundle, which has degree $1/24$, so it is ample. For $(g,n) = (0,4)$, I believe this has degree $-1$, which is anti-ample.
EDIT: Maybe the degree for $(g,n) = (0,4)$ is 1?

The degree for $(g,n)=(0,3)$ is $+1$ not $-1$.

Those classes are usually called psi classes.

The psi classes are nef and big according to Corollary 4.2 of the following link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.08568

It is straightforward to produce curves in the boundary in which psi classes have degree equal to zero.  So the classes are not ample (apparently Keel proves that they are semi-ample in positive characteristic).

@JasonStarr by (0,3) you mean (0,4) right? Also, I just talked to someone who called them "$\tau$-classes". Is that another name for these $\sigma_i\omega_f$'s?

A common notation is $\langle \tau_{k_1}\tau_{k_2}\dots\tau_{k_n}\rangle_g = \int_{\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}} \psi_1^{k_1}\psi_2^{k_2}\cdots\psi_n^{k_n}$, which may be where the $\tau$ name was coming from.

Yes, I meant to write $(g,n)=(0,4)$.  Those classes are psi classes.  I also have a paper that uses ampleness of psi classes, so I have seen this before.

I am just posting my comment as one answer.  It is a theorem of Seán Keel that the log relative dualizing sheaf on the universal family $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n+1}$ over the base scheme $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ is nef and big (since the nef and big locus is open in the base scheme $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}$, Keel's semiampleness theorem in all positive characteristics implies the invertible sheaf is nef and big over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Q}$).
Keel, Seán(1-TX) 
Basepoint freeness for nef and big line bundles in positive characteristic.
Ann. of Math. (2) 149 (1999), no.1, 253–286. 
Using this, Daebom Choi deduces that also the psi classes are nef and big, cf. Corollary 4.2 of the following.
Daebom Choi 
Complete subvarieties of $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ and a lifting problem
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.08568 
There are also some theorems about ampleness of psi classes on Kontsevich spaces, cf. Section 4 of my own article about symplectic deformation invariance of a covering family of rational surfaces (blowups of the projective plane) on compact Kähler manifolds.
Jason Starr 
Symplectic invariance of rational surfaces on Kähler manifolds. 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06412
